# getting shopping cart empty page on add to cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am getting product name was added to your shopping cart on magento 1.9. I have changed cookie settings but still getting same issue.

Can anyone resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix by increasing the cookie life time to **86400** under

```
Sytem -> Configuration -> Web -> Session and Cookie Management
```

The Reason that I found out after doing some research on internet and different forum is that in Magento, by default cookie lifetime is set to 3600 (1 hour). But if the end users computer time runs ahead of server’s time, cookies will not get set for Magento frontend as well as backend. For example, end user’s computer time is 1 hour forward than server’s time, that means the cookie (holding user’s session id) will expire as soon as user logs in or tries to add an item.

If that didt work, than try clearing your browser cookies and check....

Also one more opton is Set your cookie domain to:   `.domain.com` in Backend

Answer (score 0):

I thing it may be cache or cookie issue, try with following points.

1. Flush cache and try to add to cart in same or private window.
2. Flush cache and try to add to cart in another browser private window.